# Android gradle NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'

    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:18.0.0'

    // Note: these libraries require the "Google Repository" and "Android Repository"
    //       to be installed via the SDK manager.

    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Project build successfully, no errors no warnings.

```
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE                                  
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV71800Library UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices3225Library UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareDebugDependencies             
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE  
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE  
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE  
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE  
:nativeLibsToJar UP-TO-DATE  
:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE  
:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE  
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE  
:validateDebugSigning             
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE  
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareReleaseDependencies             
:compileReleaseAidl             
:compileReleaseRenderscript             
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE  
:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE  
:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE  
:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE  
:generateReleaseSources             
:compileRelease             
:dexRelease             
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE  
:packageRelease             
:assembleRelease             
:assemble             
:check UP-TO-DATE  
:build             

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 39.311 secs
```

But when I run project on emulator or usb device I get the error `NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder`

This problem appear only with org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3 with other libs like com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar no problem

Comment: make sure all the jar files needed was kept in the `libs` folder

Comment: It's necessary even if gralde used?

Comment: @beholderrk no, it's not necessary, as long as those are added in gradle.build as dependencies, and I don't see in your config any dependency on physical JAR files (eg. fileTree). Have you managed to solve the problem? Would be nice of you to provide answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google have native httpcore package in android SDK (v18), and this package is `httpcore:4.2.x`. In order the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime` works properly it must have the same version as native `httpcore` ie `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.1`

I downloaded `httpclient-4.2.1.jar httpmime-4.2.1.jar` libs to the `<project>/libs` folder.

Delete the `build` folder before make project.
This config solved all my problems with httpmime:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'

    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:18.0.0'

    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('debug')
    }
}
```